# Killing a subprocess started via sudo

Tags: python, subprocess, sudo

In a project I am working on, there is some code that starts up a long-running process using `sudo`:

```
subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '/usr/bin/somecommand', ...])
```

I would like to clean up this process when the parent exits.  Currently, the subprocess keeps running when the parent exits (re-attached to `init`, of course).

I am not sure of the best solution to this problem.  The code is limited to only running certain commands via sudo, and granting blanket authority to run `sudo kill` would be sketchy at best.

I don't have an open pipe to the child process that I can close (the child process is  not reading from stdin), and I am not able to modify the code of the child process.

Are there any other mechanisms that might work in this situation?

Comment: Good question. I don't think you can kill a process that is (no longer) owned by the user. I assume, from your example, that you've configured `/etc/sudoers` to allow running the program with sudo without a password. Have you considered doing the same for `killall /usr/bin/somecommand`?

Answer (score 5):

First of all I just answer the question. Though I do not think it is a good thing to do, it is what you asked for. I would wrap that child process into a small program that can listen `stdin`. Then you may `sudo` that program, and it will be able to run the process without `sudo`, and will know its `pid` and have the rights needed to kill the process when you ask it through `stdin` to do so.

However, generally such a situation means `sudo` with no password and poor security. The most common technique is to use lowering your program's privileges, not elevating them. In such case you should create a runner program that is started by superuser, than it starts your main program with lowering of privileges and listens for a pipe to communicate. When it is necessary to run  a command, your main program tells that to the runner program, and runner program does the job. When it is necessary to terminate command, you again tell this to a runner program via the pipe.

The common rules are:

1. If you need superuser rights, you should give them to the very parent process.
2. If a child process needs to do a privileged operation, it requests the top-level process to do that for him.
3. The top-level process should be kept as small as possible and do as little as possible. The larger it is, the more holes in security it creates.

That's what many applications do. The first example that comes into my mind is Apache web server (at least on *nix) that has a small top-level program and preforked working programs that are not run as root/wheel/whatever-else-is-the-superuser-username.

Answer (score 0):

This will raise `OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted` on the last line:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', '/usr/bin/somecommand', ...])
print p.stdout.read()
p.terminate()
```

Assuming sudo will not ask for a password, one workaround is to make a shell script which calls sudo …

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/bin/somecommand
```

… and then do this in Python:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("/path/to/script.sh", cwd="/path/to")
print p.stdout.read()
p.terminate()
```